# Como obtener las ultimas 5 semanas en sql server

Tags: sql-server

necesito obtener las ultimas 5 semanas de movimientos de cada pedido.
esta es la estructura de la tabla.

```
select 
No_Pedido, 
No_Tienda, 
Fecha_Operacion, 
Tipo_Operacion, 
Importe  
from MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO
 where No_Pedido=18020
 and No_Tienda=7497
```

al consultar unicamente ese pedido en esa tienda me devuelve el siguiente resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**lo que necesito son los movimientos de las ultimas 5 semanas anterior al ultimo movimiento registrado en la base.**

realice lo siguiente:

```
select 
No_Pedido, 
No_Tienda, 
Fecha_Operacion, 
Tipo_Operacion, 
Importe  
from MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO
 where No_Pedido=18020
 and No_Tienda=7497 
  group by  No_Pedido,
No_Tienda,
Fecha_Operacion,
Tipo_Operacion,
Importe
having Fecha_Operacion> DATEADD(DAY,-31,MAX(CONVERT(DATE,Fecha_Operacion)))
```

sin embargo no logro el resultado que necesito, si alguien pudiera darme alguna idea, se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: ¿Necesitas conservar los filtros por pedido y tienda? ¿O esos los vas a eliminar para obtener los movimientos de las últimas 5 semanas de todos los pedidos y todas las tiendas?

Comment: esos filtros los voy a eliminar, los coloque nada mas para mostrar el resultado que arroja la tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más efectivo es primero obtener las fechas de los últimos movimientos de cada pedido y sobre eso hacer el cálculo y filtro. Puede ser mediante un JOIN o un EXISTS. La sintaxis es un poco distinta entre ambos casos y el rendimiento de la consulta puede variar, por lo que es mejor hacer pruebas para saber cual opción es mejor para tu estructura de datos.

```
WITH cteFechasMovimientos AS(
    SELECT  No_Pedido,
            DATEADD( WK, -5, MAX( Fecha_Operacion)) AS FechaInicio,
            MAX( Fecha_Operacion)                   AS FechaFin
    FROM   MOVIMENTO_PEDIDO MP
    GROUP BY No_Pedido
)
SELECT  MP.No_Pedido, 
        MP.No_Tienda, 
        MP.Fecha_Operacion, 
        MP.Tipo_Operacion, 
        MP.Importe  
FROM MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO    MP
JOIN cteFechasMovimientos F ON MP.No_Pedido = F.No_Pedido
                           AND MP.Fecha_Operacion BETWEEN F.FechaInicio AND F.FechaFin;



SELECT  MP.No_Pedido, 
        MP.No_Tienda, 
        MP.Fecha_Operacion, 
        MP.Tipo_Operacion, 
        MP.Importe  
FROM MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO    MP
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT *
            FROM MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO F
            WHERE MP.No_Pedido = F.No_Pedido
            GROUP BY F.No_Pedido
            HAVING MP.Fecha_Operacion BETWEEN DATEADD( WK, -5, MAX( F.Fecha_Operacion))
                                          AND MAX( F.Fecha_Operacion));
```

Comment: te agradezco muchísimo, esto me sirvió, de nuevo muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir a tu código un and por ejemplo:

```
select 
No_Pedido, 
No_Tienda, 
Fecha_Operacion, 
Tipo_Operacion, 
Importe  
from MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO
 where No_Pedido=18020
 and No_Tienda=7497 
and Fecha_Operacion > '20200101' and Fecha_Operacion < '20200201'
```

o igual poner el rango de fechas que ocupes

Comment: No creo que eso ayude. El objetivo es obtener las fechas de manera automática según las fechas de los movimientos.

Comment: muchas gracias y exacto, eso lo podría hacer si quisiera jalar nada mas los movimientos de manera global de todos los pedidos de una fecha a otra. pero **lo que necesito es que de cada pedido, me jale nada mas los movimientos de las ultimas 5 semanas antes de el ultimo movimiento de cada pedido**.